# Extract capabilities for a single FHIR resource

Tags: hl7-fhir

On the Capabilities interaction (/metadata) what would be the best way to extract the capabilities for a single resource type, like Patient?

The intent is to determine the available search parameters of that resource type. Currently I can get the whole capability statement which weights around 700Kb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, there's no mechanism to do what you're interested in.  For R4 or R5 we're exploring alternatives that allow clients to retrieve more limited information.  Feel free to submit your requirements as a change request against the specification.